# Quicksorting a given list in Python, while printing each step

Tags: python, quicksort

So, my teacher, a person a little too obsessed with adding details to every homework task, has given a task that I can't think a way to do.

It's about quick-sorting in Python, and he wants us to build a function that quick-sorts a list while printing out each step. I have been using the List Comprehension method for quick-sorting up until now, but I haven't been able to figure out where and how to put my print statements.

Here's the code I currently use:

```py
def quick_sort(lst):
    if lst == []:   return []
    pivot = lst[0]
    left = [x for x in lst[1:] if x < pivot]
    right = [x for x in lst[1:] if x > pivot]
    return quick_sort(left) + [pivot] + quick_sort(right)
```

I've tried printing out the `python quick_sort(left) + [pivot] + quick_sort(right)`
before returning it, but it prints outputs that do not match with what I want. Thinking about it, it makes sense, as the List Comprehension method attempts to, kind of, sort the list by dividing it into pieces, and my function re-calls itself on each smaller partition until there are no elements left in it.

I expect that, when I input a list, for example, `[5, 1, 4, 3, 2]`, the program should at least print out the steps in a way like this (Consider that I take the first element as pivot):

```
>>> Enter the list: 5, 1, 4, 3, 2
```

`[1, 4, 3, 2, 5]` 5 is pivot, smaller values to the left, now `[1, 4, 3, 2]` should be sorted

`[1, 4, 3, 2, 5]` 1 is pivot, bigger values to the right, now `[4, 3, 2]` should be sorted

`[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]` 4 is pivot, smaller values to the left, now `[3, 2]` should be sorted

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` 3 is pivot, smaller values to the left, now `[2]` should be sorted

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` 2 is pivot, no values left, returning `[]`, and exiting the recursion

Maybe this could be done by defining another function that would store an additional list and update it each time a recursion happens in `quick_sort()`, but I haven't been able to think of that yet.

Comment: Your quicksort will discard duplicates if one is chosen as the pivot.

Comment: Anyway, can you not just print something like `left + [pivot] + right` before the recursive calls?

Comment: @Blorgbeard the problem is that OP is doing a divide-and-conquer quicksort, rather than an in-place quicksort.

Comment: I tried printing ```left + [pivot] + right``` but since each recursive call divides the list into smaller partitions, calling the ```quick_sort()``` on a partition like ```[4, 3, 2]``` will print out ```[3, 2, 4]``` without the rest of the list. That's what I meant by maybe declaring a new function that would store an additional list and update it constantly with what ```quick_sort()``` returns.

Comment: Oh right, you want to print the whole list at each step

Comment: @Prune I also believe that's my problem. But do you think it would be possible to create another function, say ```update_list()```, and my recursive ```quick_sort()``` would not call itself, but call the update function, which would first take what has been sorted in the step, and proceed by calling ```quick_sort()``` again? And if yes, would it still be considered recursion?

Comment: Yes; that's indirect recursion, but still recursion.  However, it sounds a quite awkward.  Frankly, I recommend that you bail out to the more common implementation of passing list indices for the low and high limits of this pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructor has made an invalid assumption: that you will implement the quicksort as an in-place sort, rather than the divide-and-conquer that you used.  That in-place assumption *does* have merit, in that it performs much less data movement: your routine creates three new lists on every call, rather than merely swapping list elements as needed.  However, here's a partial attempt to mollify your instructor, highlighting your method:

```
def quick_sort(lst):
    if lst == []:   return []
    pivot = lst[0]
    left = [x for x in lst[1:] if x < pivot]
    right = [x for x in lst[1:] if x > pivot]
    print(lst, pivot, "is pivot", left, "and", right, "should be sorted")
    new_list = quick_sort(left) + [pivot] + quick_sort(right)
    print("NEW", new_list)
    return new_list

quick_sort([4, 1, 5, 3, 2])
```